# What's the most efficient way to make a log entry on a server from javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, logging

Let's suppose I have a script that needs to log something on the server. I have an endpoint like `http://myServer.com/recordLog` and I can hit that with some parameters and it'll make a record. Some caveats:

- I can control what the server returns
- This will happen millions of times per day.
- Efficiency is of utmost importance.
- The script might be loaded from another server and within an iframe, so browser security issues are in play.
- I dont really care about the response at all. Even if there's a communication failure, I'm not going to do anything about it.
- I can't do anything that affects the state of the rest of the page.

My first thought was to make an ajax call -- it seems like the "modern", "right" way to do it. However, in some circumstances, that can trigger cross-domain security issues.

My other idea is to load a 1x1 pixel image or an empty `<script>` into memory. Something like:

```
var i = new Image;
i.src = "http://myserver.com/recordLog?foo=bar&baz=buz"; // returns 1x1 gif
```

or:

```
// this is similar to ajax-p, I suppose
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type= 'text/javascript';
s.src= "http://myserver.com/recordLog?foo=bar&baz=buz"; // returns empty text file
```

I'm pretty sure there's no need ever to put the image or script into the DOM. Merely setting the src causes the browser to make the request.

These two are pretty similar. The general standard seems to be to use pixels, but I think that's a hold-over. I would think an empty script would be slightly smaller to transfer. Any advantages of one or the other?

Any other ideas / methods? Any hidden gotchas I'm not thinking of (such as, perhaps, ancient browsers that wouldn't work as expected)?

Comment: Do you need to authenticate the logger?  I.e., do you care whether an attacker can fill up your log with forged log messages?

Comment: What cross-domain security issues? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit a query, why not just create a form and submit it.

```
<iframe id=invisibleiframe ...>
<form target=invisibleiframe action=log>
  <input type=hidden name=logmessage value=log>
</form>
<script>forms.log.submit()</script>
```

Comment: He mentioned XHR, that's what `make an ajax call` means. He mentioned that it doesn't work cross-domain.

Comment: Hmm... using an invisible iframe would probably work, but it seems like more overhead than the methods I'm suggesting -- I have to create a lot more elements and probably actually inject them into the DOM.

Comment: @slebetman It does work cross-domain. You cannot read the HTTP-response if the domains don't match, but you *can* send the HTTP-request.

Comment: Maybe there's a way around it, but Chrome throws an error. XMLHttpRequest cannot load [remote url]. Origin [script server] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @sprugman, XHR won't work cross-origin.  You need CORS for that.  I edited to remove all references to XHR.

Comment: @MikeSamuel CORS is not needed here, since the HTTP-response doesn't need to be accessed. The OP just wants to send the request and doesn't care about the response. A regular XHR is sufficient for this.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, the OP asks for options, not prerequisites.

Comment: @MikeSamuel What prerequisites? The OP wants to programmatically send a HTTP-request - XHR does exactly that.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, you responded that CORS "is not needed".  That is talking about what is required.  The OP asks to enumerate options.  CORS is an option.

Comment: @mike I used the wrong phrase. What I meant is CORS is not related to this issue. CORS is used to enable access to HTTP-response contents. The OP does not need to access the HTTP-response which means that CORS is off-topic in this case. And let me repeat myself that XHR is a legitimate solution for this issue (despite your comment above suggesting that it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem with this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open( 'GET', 'http://myserver.com/recordLog?foo=bar&baz=buz' );
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Maybe there's a way around it, but if I run that from someOtherServer.com, Chrome throws an error. XMLHttpRequest cannot load [remote url]. Origin [script server] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @sprugman Chrome and other browsers will throw an error because your page is not allowed to access the HTTP-response. But that's **irrelevant** - you don't need the server-response as you stated in your question. The important thing is that the HTTP-request **will be made** regardless, so your server will receive the request.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an `iframe` and point to some logging URL that doesn't return anything.

Comment: Empty iframe is very similar to empty script idea, but maybe slightly safer somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use a [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosql) database for storing log messages, such as [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). CouchDB for example, stores JSON documents and you interact with the server using a RESTful API. MongoDB on the other hand, stores documents in BSON format (a binary format inspired by JSON). There are a lot of examples that will get you going on their sites.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, that's about how to create/store the log entry on the server-side, but has nothing to do with how to communicate the log entry from the browser to the server.

Comment: As I previously said, you can interact with the server through an RESTful interface, that is, you can send log messages via AJAX directly to the database server, in JSON format. These DBMS are highly optimized for scenarios like this.

Comment: You can look at this article for an overview: [CouchDB for access log aggregation and analysis](http://userprimary.net/posts/2009/06/13/couchdb-for-access-log-aggregation-and-analysis/).

Comment: but I still have the cross-domain issue with using AJAX. What the server does with the request is irrelevant to the discussion.